# Microsoft Office Help shows up in HTML...?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office, help-files

I cannot access my Microsoft help files though any Office application.

[image: Help files]

Facts:

- Windows XP
- Office 2007
- Works for other user accounts on the same machine
- Checked file extensions - HTML, HTM, XHTML and XML all are associated with IE
- Tried to repair Office and rebooted machine - no luck

Note: If you click on the links in the sidebar in the Help dialog box, the pages display correctly. It just does not display when initially opening or while searching.

Comment: Technically XML but w/e. HTML, HTM, XHTML and XML should all be
associated with IE

Comment: I've already tried doing this; they are associated with IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this utility: [Fix Windows XP Help](http://www.dougknox.com/xp/utils/FixWinXPHelp.zip).

Just in case, create a system restore point before running the exe.

Comment: Interesting. It looks like this application just checks file extensions and restores them to default? I'll have to take a look. Have you ever used this utility before?

Comment: Years ago I used it on my XP laptop. I had a similar issue with the help files due to some registry mess, and it worked. I'm not sure if it solves your problem, but it is worth a try.

Comment: I tried this application and it said the registry was OK. After that I ran CCleaner also did not help :(